# Auto Grading MathQuill and/or MathJax

Tags: mathjax, mathquill

I have an online assessment platform, and I am trying to auto-grade math questions. The student will enter the question through our MathQuill interface that is working nicely. (for both desktop and tablets)

However, I am running into issues figuring out how to "evaluate" MathQuill or MathJax server side. And I want to do this because lets say the correct answer is 1/2, but the student can enter 2/4, 3/6, 4/8, etc... And all those answers will evaluate to the correct answer.

Does anyone know of a way to do this server side? Is there a service(API) that I can call that will help me with this?

Finally, I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There really aren't any easy answers.

Some things people do:

- [Desmos](http://desmos.com) wrote a custom LaTeX parser and evaluator
- [SwiftCalcs](http://swiftcalcs.com) wrote a custom LaTeX parser to convert to the string format expected by the [Giac](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/giac.html) computer algebra system, which they to JS with Emscripten
- [This MathQuill community member](https://mathquill.slack.com/archives/mathquill/p1463936507001337) has been trying to use the Wolfram|Alpha API
- in the past, I've massaged the `.text()` output from MathQuill into something usable by [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) or [Math.js](http://mathjs.org)